# Remove CMYK colors to keep only black from a PNG

Tags: python, pdf, png

I'm trying to remove the colors from a PNG there is a way to do it ? My goal is to import my image in a PDF using Python, I tryed first with an SVG file but impossible to import, nothing appears with no error. So I wanted to try with a PNG but still hard to import.
Now I have an image with these percentage of colors :

[image: Percentage of CMYK colors in my picture]

And my final result would be this :

[image: Expected result]

I already tried with openCV but no result from it, I'm looking for a solution since few days.

```
file = "app\\static\\img\\Picto CE_MAROC_H_6mm.png"
src = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
src[:,:,2] = np.zeros([src.shape[0], src.shape[1]])
cv2.imwrite(file,src)
```

Thanks in advance for your help ! :)

Comment: Please provide representative images showing what you start with and what you hope to end up with. What will happen where you *"remove colours"*? Will it become transparent? Grey? What has SVG got to do with your question? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### What does it mean to only have a K channel?

Most applications use RGB or RGBA, whereas the CMYK color space is typically for printed material. We should translate what does it mean for an image to only use the K channel.

First, let's look the formulas to convert the [CMYK colorspace to RGB](https://www.101computing.net/cmyk-to-rgb-conversion-algorithm/). We will assume that C, M, K are on a 0-100 integer scale:

```
R = 255 * (1 - C/100) * (1 - K/100)  
G = 255 * (1 - M/100) * (1 - K/100)  
B = 255 * (1 - Y/100) * (1 - K/100)
```

Since we only care for the K channel, we will set C, Y, and M to 0. This simplifies the formulas to:

```
R = 255 * (1 - K/100)  
G = 255 * (1 - K/100)  
B = 255 * (1 - K/100)
```

Notice that R = G = B when only the K channel is set. This produces a gray monochrome throughout the image, effectively making it [**grayscale**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale). As such, the goal would be to produce a grayscale image given a RGBA image input.

### Converting color to grayscale

Converting a color to its grayscale component is simply done by preserving the luminance of the original image in a gray monochrome palette. To do so, a formula must be defined which takes in a RGB input and returns a single value Y, creating a YYY color on the gray monochrome scale. This can simply be done by assigning each color a coefficient to scale how much an effect each has on luminance. Since the human eye is most sensitive to G, R, then B, we would want to assign a high coefficient to G and a low coefficient to B. The most common grayscale calculation used is [luma coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Luma_coding_in_video_systems) for color TV and video systems:

```
Y = round(0.229 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B)
```

### Converting an image to only use the K channel in Python

Now knowing the above information, we can convert an image to only use the K channel. For this, we can use [imageio](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/) which can provide pixel information in RGB format. Since image data is given as an n dimensional array, we can also use [numpy](https://numpy.org/) to abstract any loops needed to apply a grayscale to every pixel.

I will be using the [`imageio.v3`](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/core_v3.html) module as that is the most recent API as of this post. Loading in the image can be done by calling `imageio.v3.imread` and passing in the location of the image.

First, we want to get a luminance value for each pixel in the image. This can be done by taking the dot product of the image and the coefficients of the luminance formula. This will produce a 2D array as (height, width, RGB) x (RGB) = (height, width). We also need to round the values and cast each to a unsigned 8-bit integer to get our values into the 0-255 integer color range.

```
import numpy as np

# For some image `im` loaded by `#imread`

# The coefficients for converting an RGB color to its luminance value
grayscale_coef = [0.299, 0.587, 0.114]

# Create a 2D array where any pixel (height, width) translates to a single luminance  value
grayscale = np.dot(im, grayscale_coef)

# Round the each luminance value and convert to a 0-255 range
grayscale = np.round(grayscale).astype(np.uint8)
```

### Saving as CMYK

Now that we have the value to put into the K channel, we need to reconstruct the 3D array setting the CMY channels to 0 and then outputting to an image format that supports CMYK (JPG, TIFF, etc.). For this, we can use [`pillow`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

```
from PIL import Image

# Create the CMY channels initialized to 0
cmy = np.zeros(grayscale.shape + (3,))

# Stack the CMY and K channels together
# Cast type to unsigned byte to avoid channel turning completely black
cmyk = np.dstack((cmy, grayscale)).astype(np.uint8)

# Read image from CMYK array buffer
result = Image.fromarray(cmyk, mode="CMYK")

# Save image in a supported format
result.save("<filename_here>.jpg")
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't works for me :/ I did exactly what you wrote but I still have Cyan, Magenta and Yellow colors in my image...

Comment: Apologies, I realized that PNG doesn't support CMYK, so I updated the above example to force the calculated grayscale to be put into a CMYK channel where the CMY values are all 0. This should achieve the result you're looking for now.